# Optimal data tree structure for folder hierarchy

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, tags, directory-structure

Imagine I have 4 files identified by a given list of unordered bu non-repeating tags ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'). For example:

```
folder_tags_dict = {  
'f1': ['A', 'B'],  
'f2': ['A', 'C', 'D'],  
'f3': ['D'],  
'f4': ['C', 'A']  
}
```

I would like to construct a data tree where every file is uniquely identified by the list of tags (just like a folder structure), provided by the configuration above.
The solution is not unique. The following two trees are possible solutions to this problem:

Tree1:

```
A --- B --- f1  
 \--- C --- D --- f2  
       \--- f4  
D --- f3
```

Tree2:

```
C --- A --- D --- f2  
 \--- A --- f4  
A --- B --- f1  
D --- f3
```

The questions is:

**Is there an algorithm that takes the configuration in folder_tags_dict and optimizes the data tree generation hierarchy in order to minimize the number of total edges in that tree?**

In the previous case, Tree1 is a better solution (7 edges) than Tree2 (8 edges).

I know how to code in Python, but my knowledge in data structures is limited. This could be used to find the optimal way of making a folder structure where every file is identified by a set of tags. However, when the number of files and tags are in the hundreds, an efficient algorithm is needed and brute force is not an option.

Comment: Can a single list of tags have duplicates, like `'f1': ['A', 'A']`?

Comment: Hi! No, the tags are unique! I shall edit the initial post to clarify!

Comment: If you have a graph rather than tree, you'll achieve the optimal solution. Make a list of unique file names and a tuple of tuples of folder names which correspond to the file. You can then calculate the inverse look up tavle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
from contextlib import suppress
from itertools import chain
from typing import Any


class Node:
    def __init__(self, tag: Any, tags_dict) -> None:
        self.tag = tag
        self.item = None
        self.children = {}
        self.build_node(tags_dict)

    def get_edges(self):
        edges = sum([ch.get_edges() + 1 for _, ch in self.children.items()])
        return edges + 1 if self.item is not None else edges

    def get_children(self):
        return {f"{key}-{ch.item}": ch.get_children() for key, ch in self.children.items()}

    def build_node(self, tags_dict):
        items = [key for key, value in tags_dict.items() if len(value) == 0]
        if items:
            self.item = items[0]

        mult_tag = {key: value for key, value in tags_dict.items() if len(value) > 0}
        while len(mult_tag.keys()) > 0:
            tag = self.get_best_tag(mult_tag)
            if not tag:
                tag = [value[0] for key, value in mult_tag.items() if len(value) == 1][0]

            contains_tag_dict = {key: value for key, value in mult_tag.items() if tag in value}
            reduced_tags_dict = self.reduce_dict(contains_tag_dict, tag)
            self.children[tag] = self.subtree(tag, reduced_tags_dict)

            mult_tag = {key: value for key, value in mult_tag.items() if tag not in value}

    @classmethod
    def subtree(cls, tag, tags_dict):
        return cls(tag, tags_dict)

    @staticmethod
    def reduce_dict(tags_dict, tag):
        new_tags_dict = {}
        for key, item in tags_dict.items():
            if len(item) > 0:
                new_tags_dict[key] = [t for t in item if t != tag]
        return new_tags_dict

    @staticmethod
    def get_best_tag(tags_dict):
        all_tag_lists = [item for _, item in tags_dict.items()]
        tags_count = Counter(chain(*all_tag_lists))
        with suppress(Exception):
            return tags_count.most_common()[0][0]


folder_tags_dict = {
    'f1': ['A', 'B'],
    'f2': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
    'f3': ['D'],
    'f4': ['C', 'A']
}

tree = Node("root", folder_tags_dict)

print("TREE: ", tree.get_children())
print("EDGES(from root): ", tree.get_edges())
```

Comment: I think it does the job indeed!! I will try some extra things tomorrow before setting it solved!

Comment: Nice :). Please don't forget to mark it as a solution if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
def to_tree(d):
   t = defaultdict(list)
   for a, *b in d:
      t[a].append(b)
   return {a:to_tree(b) if len(b) > 1 else b[0] for a, b in t.items()}
```

---

```
import json
folder_tags_dict = {'f1': ['A', 'B'], 'f2': ['A', 'C', 'D'], 'f3': ['D'], 'f4': ['C', 'A']}
c = Counter([j for b in folder_tags_dict.values() for j in b])
t_f = [[*sorted(b, key=lambda x:c[x], reverse=True), a] for a, b in folder_tags_dict.items()]
print(json.dumps(to_tree(t_f), indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "A": {
        "B": [
            "f1"
        ],
        "C": {
            "D": [
                "f2"
            ],
            "f4": []
        }
    },
    "D": [
        "f3"
    ]
}
```